# Different keywords on my sub pages and their impact on my SEO

Tags: seo, keywords

I am new to SEO and I am trying my best but I have few questions.

My website is familiar with gaming industry and I have 5 gaming niches on it (5 main sub pages) to make it simplier: 1. Mydomain.com Mydomain.com/niche1 Mydomain.com/niche2 etc

Keywords on mydomain.com are mostly for niche 1 and few for every niche.

Every sub page has its own keywords.

My question is, is it good that most of the main subpages have different keywords? Or shall my keywords be the same as the ones on the main page?

Answer (score 1):

each of your pages should have target keyword or key phrase. 
It is harmful for your SEO to have the same target keyword on more than two pages. 
Mydomain.com/niche1      >>>> Target Keyword 1
Mydomain.com/niche2      >>>> Target Keyword 2 
etc...

if you do not follow this rule, your pages compete with each other for the same keyword on google SERP and it is the negative point for your rating.

Comment: That was pretty much what I was asking for. Although, building backlinks for may main domain with anchor text suiting that domains keywords - do this also affect my other sub pages positively?

Comment: @user102122 Links to your main domain/root domain will help develop your domain authority, if done properly. This won't necessarily help you to track better for any particular keyword it phrase, but can help you to develop authority on the whole.